# A question about t-structures in derived category

Tags: rt.representation-theory, derived-categories, tilting

Let R be a ring and $_{R}P$ be a projective module, my question is whether $P^{\perp_{>0}}:=\{X\in D(R)|Hom(P,X[i])=0, i>0\}$ is an aisle i.e.  if $(P^{\perp_{>0}}, (P^{\perp_{>0}})^{\perp}[1])$ is a t-structure in D(R)

Comment: It follows from the main result in "Construction of t-structures and equivalences of derived categories". Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. 355 (2003), no. 6, 2523–2543. https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/2003-355-06/S0002-9947-03-03261-6/

Comment: @LeoAlonso Probably I'm missing something easy, but Theorem 3.4 of your paper (which I think is what you mean by the main result?) states that a cocomplete pre-aisle generated by a set of objects is an aisle. Is it clear that  $P^{\perp_{>0}}$ is generated by a set of objects? (Or even that it is cocomplete, if $P$ is not finitely generated?)

Comment: Perhaps in this situation $P^{\perp_{>0}}$ agrees with the smallest cocomplete pre-aisle generated by $P$. I have to admit I have not checked this, so I gave this hint to the OP just in case it would be of some help.